# How to read and display user's rank which is set as default in the beginning

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I added a new column COL_5 to my SQLite database and it's called "rank". Every user registered starts with rank set as "Australopithecus afarensis" which should be displayed in UserPanelActivity.java. What I did is I managed to display nickname of user (SignInActivity) but I have trouble with checking current rank and then display it on the screen.

Code looks like this:

DatabaseHelper:

```
package com.pracainzynierska.inzynierka;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME="register.db";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME="registeruser";
    public static final String COL_1 ="ID";
    public static final String COL_2 ="username";
    public static final String COL_3 ="mail_address";
    public static final String COL_4 ="password";
    public static final String COL_5 = "rank";
    //public static final String COL_6 = "dailytip";

    public DatabaseHelper(@Nullable Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME,null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE registeruser (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,username TEXT, mail_address TEXT, password TEXT, rank TEXT DEFAULT 'Australopithecus afarensis')");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public long addUser(String user, String password, String mail_address) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put("username", user);
        contentValues.put("password", password);
        contentValues.put("mail_address", mail_address);
        long res = db.insert("registeruser", null, contentValues);
        db.close();
        return res;
    }

        public boolean checkUser(String username, String password)
        {
            String[] columns = {COL_1};
            SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
            String selection = COL_2 + "=?" + " and " + COL_4 + "=?";
            String[] selectionArgs = {username, password};
            Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME, columns,selection,selectionArgs,null,null,null);
            int count = cursor.getCount();
            cursor.close();
            db.close();

            if(count>0)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
    }
```

SignInActivity:

```
package com.pracainzynierska.inzynierka;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.facebook.CallbackManager;

public class SignInActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private TextView register_text;
    public static CallbackManager callbackManager;
    DatabaseHelper db;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        db = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_in);

        final EditText usernameEditText = findViewById(R.id.username);
        final EditText passwordEditText = findViewById(R.id.password);
        final Button loginButton = findViewById(R.id.login);
        final ProgressBar loadingProgressBar = findViewById(R.id.loading);
        usernameEditText.requestFocus();
        register_text = findViewById(R.id.register_text);

        register_text.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent registerIntent = new Intent(SignInActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class);
                startActivity(registerIntent);
            }
        });

        loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String user = usernameEditText.getText().toString().trim();
                String pwd = passwordEditText.getText().toString().trim();
                Boolean res = db.checkUser(user,pwd);
                if(res == true)
                {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(SignInActivity.this,UserPanelActivity.class);
                    Intent intentPopUp = new Intent(SignInActivity.this, PopUpActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("username",user);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    startActivity(intentPopUp);
                    Toast.makeText(SignInActivity.this,"Welcome " + user + "!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(SignInActivity.this,"There is a problem with singing in!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    usernameEditText.setText("");
                    passwordEditText.setText("");
                    usernameEditText.requestFocus();
                }

            }
        });
    }
}
```

UserPanelActivity:

```
package com.pracainzynierska.inzynierka;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class UserPanelActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button settings_btn, progress_btn, dailychallenge_btn, premium_btn, logout_btn, training_btn;
    private TextView NickNameText, rankText;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_panel);
        String username = getIntent().getStringExtra("username");
        //String rank = getIntent().getStringExtra("rank");

        NickNameText =  findViewById(R.id.nickname);
        NickNameText.setText(username);

        //here I'd like to display rank
        rankText = findViewById(R.id.rank);
        rankText.setText(rank);


        settings_btn = findViewById(R.id.settings_user_panel_button);
        settings_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Settings();
            }
        });

        progress_btn = findViewById(R.id.progress_button);
        progress_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                MyProgress();
            }
        });

        dailychallenge_btn = findViewById(R.id.challenge_button);
        dailychallenge_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                DailyChallenge();
            }
        });

        premium_btn = findViewById(R.id.premium_button);
        premium_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Premium();
            }
        });

        logout_btn = findViewById(R.id.logout_button);
        logout_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                BackToMenu();
                finish();
            }
        });

        training_btn = findViewById(R.id.start_freetraining_button);
        training_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Training();
            }
        });


    }

    private void Training() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, FillTheTextActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    private void BackToMenu() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    private void Premium() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,PremiumActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    private void DailyChallenge() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,DailyChallengeActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    private void MyProgress() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,MyProgressActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    private void Settings() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```

Every help is kindly seen, thanks in advance :)

Comment: Did you alter the table schema? Also, what error are you seeing? My guess is that you didn't change the schema version.

Comment: Also, migrate to Room if possible or if your school is allows it. https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room#java

Comment: I don't know how to get value from COL_5 and display it on the screen in UserPanelActivity.

Comment: When you say that you do not know how to do it, do you mean you do not know how to formulate the SQL query to do so? Or is it something else?

Comment: Actually I don't know how to create a method in DatabaseHelper.

Answer (score 0):

Create a method like this in your `DatabaseHelper` class:

```
public String getRank(int id) {
    String query = "SELECT rank from " + TABLE_NAME + " where ID = " + id;
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();

    try {
       return db.rawQuery(query, null).getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(rank));
    } catch (Exception e) {
       return "";
    }
}
```

[Source](https://guides.codepath.com/android/local-databases-with-sqliteopenhelper)